# How to make a use of decorators on a task function in a dag template

Tags: python, decorator

I have almost 20 functions, which i wrote a decorator for, instead of injecting the same code within each function.So my decorator should check if each function return a 500 response status code then raise an exception.Can anyone give me more clarity?

This is the decorator I wrote

```
def check_tasks_failed(a_func):
    """
     Wrapper function to check whether a task_failed
    :param task_id:
    :param kwargs:
    :param kwargs:
    :param a_func:
    :return:

    """
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        task_id_resp_status_code = a_func(**kwargs).status_code
        if task_id_resp_status_code in [500]: # Check here what are the criterion for the task to fail
           raise ValueError('invalid return status 500')
    return wrapper
```

This is the function which needs to be decorator as an example.

```
@check_tasks_failed
def get_naming_(**kwargs) -> requests:
    """Get job from custom_etl."""
    try:
        naming_res = get_custom_etl_job(VALIDATED_CONTAINER,
                                                 VALIDATED_CONTAINER,
                                                 VALIDATED_CONTAINER,
                                                 **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        return {'success':False , 'reason': f'{e}'}
```

My expect result should be an exception raised when get_naming_  failed the following exception `raise ValueError('invalid return status 500')`

Comment: There are things wrong with your wrapped function `get_naming_`.  If an exception occurs in the call to get_custom_etl_job, the function catches the exception and tries to return a dictionary; but that won't work because there is no variable named 'e' so `f'{e}'` will raise another Exception.   If no exception occurs from the first call, your function does nothing and returns None.  So the wrapper function will crash because it expects the function return value to have an attribute named "status_code."  Fix these problems and try again.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Thanks for the heads.  So I need to take out the exception handling in my get_naming function right ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all the details of what you're trying to do. But I do understand that your decorator function assumes that the object returned by the decorated function will have an attribute named `status_code`.  Your function doesn't return any such thing, so you must fix that.  It is fine if the decorated function raises an exception - if it's not caught in the decorator it will be propagated to the caller, like any exception.